# Android Studio - How to make Vertical Line Guides Darker in the Code Editor?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to change the look of something in the main code Editor..
In Android Studio, when you're typing out your Code (Java, as well as the XML), do you know how for each "Method", or 'Block of Code', there is a very thin grey vertical line on the left side of each bunch of code, to let you know where your Method begins and ends? I want to make that lightgrey line DARKER!
so, 
1) How can I edit my settings to make those lines darker, to see them better? 
and 
2) What exactly are those lines called, so I know how to identify them by name in the future?
Sorry for the silly question! But it would definitely help me alot..
Thanks!

Comment: Those lines are for align purpose, your code looks good.

change color as shown in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called **Vertical Indent Guides**.

You can edit their color by going to:

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General`.

There open the node `Code` and find two entries `Selected vertical indent guide` and `Vertical indent guide`. For each of them you can edit their `Background` color at right panel.

[image]

Comment: By the way, I really dig your color scheme.. What all did you change? I see that you set it to Darcula, but clearly its been customized.. I wouldn't mind having that same theme from the picture you posted! My eyes kill me, but I just don't like the stock Darcula as-is. However, customizing it may be amazing. Is there a file of somekind you might be able to send me or something along those lines for an easy way to replicate your theme?

Comment: My scheme is the same default Darcula. I have only customized its font size, because of my eyes.